# IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "rawPrediction" does not exist.' in spark dataframe using Binary classification evaluator

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, nlp

I am trying to evaluate my model using Binaryclassification evaluator but i keep getting the above error despite 'rawPrediction' actually existing.

I am running an NLP model using Logistic regression, fitting and transforming went well but evaluating has been the problem

I have tried changing the evaluator to multiclass and regression even though its a classification problem but the same error persists

```
# creating bag of word model
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol = 'bagofwords', outputCol='vectors')    #features
si = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'Sentiment', outputCol = 'label')    #labels

lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol = 'vectors', labelCol = 'label', maxIter = 10, regParam = 0.3, elasticNetParam = 0.8)

pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [cv, si, lr])

model = pipeline.fit(df_train)

prediction = model.transform(df_test)
prediction.take(1)

[Row(Sentiment='negative', text='!!!!!!TO AVOID!!!!!\n\nFirst of all,    as we enter, the host was very rude (and seemed not to like his job). We get seated, and then my husband had to GET UP to ask for menus and water. After getting it, we ask for the 2 for 22$ menu, we were told the boss at this location was not offering it anymore. The 2 for 22$ being the main appeal of the restaurant, we got up and left to go to the Sherbrooke location. \n\n\nI have been to the sherbrooke location before and still now i have nothing to complain about. A1 service.\n\nWhat a shame for the Madisons restaurant line.', bagofwords=['main', 'still', 'seated', 'what', 'rude', 'not', 'nothing', 'then', 'location', 'got', 'sherbrooke', 'get', 'appeal', 'as', 'enter', 'offering', 'left', 'first', 'madisons', 'been', 'husband', 'told', 'the', 'sherbrooke', 'ask', 'get', 'to', 'being', 'go', 'after', 'anymore', 'a', 'very', 'like', 'menus', 'menu', 'getting', 'service', 'line', 'restaurant', 'avoid', 'complain', 'job', 'host', 'seemed', 'shame', 'boss', 'up', 'water'], vectors=SparseVector(191243, {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 7: 1.0, 9: 1.0, 12: 1.0, 13: 2.0, 14: 1.0, 25: 1.0, 31: 1.0, 40: 1.0, 65: 1.0, 78: 1.0, 81: 1.0, 87: 1.0, 98: 1.0, 105: 1.0, 120: 1.0, 125: 1.0, 146: 1.0, 187: 1.0, 193: 1.0, 209: 1.0, 215: 1.0, 218: 1.0, 228: 1.0, 282: 1.0, 283: 1.0, 308: 1.0, 317: 1.0, 330: 1.0, 420: 1.0, 422: 1.0, 463: 1.0, 503: 1.0, 612: 1.0, 876: 1.0, 1202: 1.0, 1277: 1.0, 1584: 1.0, 1588: 1.0, 1602: 1.0, 1714: 1.0, 1968: 1.0, 3140: 1.0, 4329: 1.0, 19856: 2.0, 51462: 1.0}), label=1.0, rawPrediction=DenseVector([1.0612, -1.0612]), probability=DenseVector([0.7429, 0.2571]), prediction=0.0)]


from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator

assess = BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setMetricName('areaUnderROC').setLabelCol('label').setRawPredictionCol('rawPrediction')

assess.evaluate(df_test)
```

I expect to get a value or metric that indicates accuracy or a semblance of it but i keep getting this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-d1448386660e> in <module>()
  5 #eval =  RegressionEvaluator().setMetricName('rmse').setLabelCol('label').setPredictionCol('prediction')
  6 
----> 7 assess.evaluate(df_test)

/usr/local/src/spark21master/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py in   evaluate(self, dataset, params)
 67                 return self.copy(params)._evaluate(dataset)
 68             else:
---> 69                 return self._evaluate(dataset)
     70         else:
     71             raise ValueError("Params must be a param map but got %s." % type(params))

/usr/local/src/spark21master/spark/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py in _evaluate(self, dataset)
 97         """
 98         self._transfer_params_to_java()
---> 99         return self._java_obj.evaluate(dataset._jdf)
100 
101     def isLargerBetter(self):

/usr/local/src/spark21master/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/src/spark21master/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "rawPrediction" does not exist.'
```

Comment: You should use the `prediction` dataframe not `df_test` for evaluation.

Comment: damn...how did i miss that? Thanks a lot